# Docker Remote API Filter Exited

Tags: docker

I see in the Docker Remote API Docs that filter can be used to filter on status but I'm unsure how to form the request:

https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.16/#list-containers

```
GET /containers/json?filters=status[exited] ?????
```

How should this be formatted to display ONLY exited containers?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[jwodder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744178/jwodder) is [correct on the filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28054296/1318694) but I wanted to go through this step by step as I wasn't familiar with the Go data types.

The [Docker API documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/#list-containers) refers to using a `map[string][]string` for a filter, which is a Go map (hash table)

- `map[string]` defines a map with keys of type `string`
- `[]string` is the type definition for the values in the map.  A slice
  `[]` is an array without fixed length. Then the slice is made up of
  `string` values.

So the API requires a hash map of arrays containing strings. This [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/rpAOf-5H6P) demonstrates marshalling the Go filter data:

```
mapS := map[string][]string{ "status":[]string{"exited"} }
```

Into JSON:

```
{ "status": [ "exited" ] }
```

So adding that JSON to the Docker API request you get:

```
GET /containers/json?all=1&filters={%22status%22:[%22exited%22]}
```

`all=1` is included to report exited containers (like `-a` on the command line).

It might be easier for non Go people if they just documented the JSON structure for the API : /

Comment: I've tried escaping the quotes in the browser and using curl but both give me no results. How can I get a valid response with this request?

Comment: You need to add `all=1` for `exited` to be reported. answer updated

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was missing. This worked for me: http://localhost:5555/containers/json?all=1&filters={%22status%22:%5B%22exited%22%5D}

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8):

The most elegant way to use docker with curl and don't bother with encoding I found in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86737/26046). Basically, it's tell curl to use data as query parameter and encode it. To get exited container the query may look like:

```
curl -G -XGET "http://localhost:5555/containers/json" \
    -d 'all=1' \
    --data-urlencode 'filters={"status":["exited"]}' | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 5):

By my reading of the docs, it should be:

```
GET /containers/json?filters={"status":["exited"]}
```

Some of that might need to be URL-encoded, though.

Comment: What's the correct way to encode the URL? http://localhost:5555/containers/json?filters={%27status%27%3A%5B%27exited%27%5D} isn't working.

Comment: curl -X GET http://localhost:5555/containers/json?filters=%7B%22status%22%3A%5B%22exited%22%5D%7D returned [] while curl -X GET http://localhost:5555/containers/json?all=1 returns correctly