# How to get the name of a Docker container using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-container, docker-api

I hope someone will be able to help me. I'm using [Dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) to make actions on my Docker containers via JavaScript.

I have some hard times to get the name of a single container. The request is "get the name of the container who has the id XXX" but I can't make it works.

To do that I used `listContainers` and  I tried to play with the options:

```
docker.listContainers({id: idContainer}, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, containers) {
  if (containers != null) {
      containers.forEach(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(containerInfo) {
          if(containerInfo.Names[0].startsWith("/")){
             containerInfo.Names[0] = containerInfo.Names[0].substr(1);
             console.log( containerInfo.Names[0]);
          }
      }));
  }
}));
```

*where idContainer is the id of a known container*

But the output contains the name of ALL containers.

I really hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Docker API docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.28/#operation/ContainerList), my take is that your call parameters are malformed maybe.

Instead of:

```
docker.listContainers({ id: idContainer }, function (...) {...});
```

You need to specify:

```
docker.listContainers({ filters: { id: idContainer } }, function (...) {...});
```

In the docs, the id parameters is inside the filter parameter group.

Comment: it's strange it's still returns me all the containers, you have an idea why ?

Comment: I have not dealt with docker api. To investigate you could look at the req structure going out and compare it to a test you can do doing the same command via curl or postman directly to the docker api daemon.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I mark your answer as the right one because it's right (yea it makes no sense) thank you

Comment: It peaked my curiosity, so I've tried curl with the help of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39976683/docker-api-can-t-apply-json-filters and https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2015/11/12/using-curl-and-the-unix-socket-to-talk-to-the-docker-api/. What I found is that the command does not work in direct api when doing `filters: { id: someid }` but `fitlers: { id: [someid] }`. It needs the id as array for some reason.  For ex: `curl -g --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/json'?filters=%7B%22id%22%3A%5B%2294115da2a95d%22%5D%7D'`

Comment: thank you for the help, and yeah I had founded this Github issue https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2515 where the guy had to add [brackets]. But for me it's still not work, did it worked for you ?

Comment: Last comment: Hi, finally it's ok I can use it thank you !